# Linux gedit plugins "go to definition"

Tags: c, plugins, gedit, gedit-plugin

I am new to linux and gedit.

I downloaded some plugins from the gedit-plugins and I am looking for plugin like "go to defenition".

Already tried to search on google but nothing work.

I have gedit version 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other people plugins or.. you can CREATE your own plugins writing a BASH SCRIPT inside the MANAGE EXTERNAL TOOLS window (**install seahorse plugin first** then enable EXTERNAL TOOLS option in the plugins tab of GEDIT preferences)

EXAMPLE: using the abvove method you can ENCRYPT some SELECTED LINES in an open document with GEDIT, look my publication at https://superuser.com/questions/1781454/how-to-encrypt-lines-or-document-with-gedit

If you are new to LINUX: a BASH script is a sequence of CLI (aka SHELL, aka TERMINAL) commands that looks like an good old MICROSOFT BATCH FILE or "file.bat"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34314125)